# Process supervisor taking care of their I/O

Tags: c, shell, unix, parallel-processing, process

I am trying to write a programs that is processing data. And for example I want to run 5 of them and they can run in parallel.I have already written shell like program with lexer and parser but I don't know how to manage these processes. Can anyone give me any tips because I'm stuck and have no idea what to do next?

Comment: Show what you have done so far by including a [mcve].  Be sure to include what inputs were used, and what output was expected and where the problem occurs.  If you have not yet written any code because you do not know how, then reading more, or studying more, is your first step.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140348/13422

Comment: Although that example reads process output sequentially. You may need to use `select`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [wait()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) and [pipe()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

You can find tons of examples if you google with those keywords. Hope it helps.

Comment: As the question refers to a code project that is not even started, it is impossible to provide a good answer for any existing problems with that code.   I suggest reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)